# How to bulk insert in cassandra DB using spring-data

Tags: spring-boot, multithreading, cassandra-3.0, spring-data-cassandra

I want to insert 10 million entries in a cassandra DB table. what is the most efficient way of doing it?

I tried insertion using scheduler and used multithreading but don't think this is effective at all.